# Chrome does not autofill passwords

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I am logged in in Chrome with my Google account.

However, Chrome does not autofill passwords from that account.

Settings->Autofill->Passwords gives this:
[image]

No saved passwords, but I can login to my Google Account with the link. When I click the link, I get to passwords.google.com and see all (masked) passwords from my account. I don't need to login more than the first time in order to see them.

A "Clear bookmarks, history, passwords" upon turning off Sync does work the next time I login... until it breaks again. I don't want to need to take this step all the time.

How do I make Chrome get the login information and autofill it in login forms?

---

Edit 5 months later (Feb 2022): this happens again. My passwords are in my account, I am logged in in the browser, Chrome suggests usernames, but does not fill in passwords.

Solved with "Turn off sync", and clear passwords/cookies/cache as suggested in the dialog tick box. I don't think this is an expected feature :)

Comment: Passwords seem to be working fine here. Consider uninstalling Chrome and your Chrome Profile. Restart. Install the newest version of Chrome and set it up again.

Comment: If you enter manually a password, does Chrome offer to keep it, and is it then truly kept? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @John Fresh install from today.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it offers to keep it. But it does not autofill it next time.

Comment: Try: (1) Check for conflict with some browser extension, by using Incognito mode. (2) Clear Browsing Data, (3) Create a new Chrome user profile and check if it works for it.

Comment: Can you try with a brand new google account you have not used before, then find some passworded sites to test.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Recent edit says that clearing bookmarks, history, and password while turning off Sync did the trick. I don't think it's a problem with the account, but with local data/settings?

Comment: I gave up trying to use the sync as it constantly signed out when signing in to other google accounts - Glad you got it sorted

Comment: @JohnnyVegas It's only sorted until next time though. I don't want to Sync off, clear everything, all the time. My guess is that this will work for about a week.

Comment: You could look for an alternative like [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/), which will also free you from the dependence on Chrome.

Comment: Do you have another computer you can test it on with the same account? Then you will at least know if it's a google problem or your specific PC problem.

Comment: Password for main account must be always entered, not like passwords "inside" this user. This is from a security reason.

Comment: @pbies Not true. When I Turn Sync Off, and clear cookies/history/passwords, then turn sync on again, it works as I expect. For a while. Only that I need to Allow/Block sites that want to know location, send notifications, ... all over again.

Comment: @Gauthier but you are still logged in.

Comment: @pbies Turning off sync logs me off too, from the browser itself even.

Comment: @Gauthier and then you need to provide password to login.

Comment: @pbies Once, at opening Chrome, yes. Not for every password fill I require, which is the problem I'm having (was having. But I solved it once before and it came back after a couple of weeks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens every few months, and my current work-around is this:

- turn off sync
- in the confirmation dialog, tick the option to clear cache and cookies and passwords
- chrome starts in some kind of standard vanilla mode
- turn on sync again

You lose local data, but the passwords get filled in again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact problem. It seemed to do with the fact that I have more than one Google account and for whatever reason, Chrome kept defaulting to the wrong one (little used, no saved passwords). Though it was asking me if I wanted to save passwords, those were going to my primary Google account and not being saved into this other profile. Go figure! I signed out of all Google accounts, then signed back into both Google and Chrome with my primary account and it's all working again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea, but Chrome manages to get the usernames, it's just the passwords. When I go to settings, autofill, passwords, and to the link in the screenshot of my question, it asks for password every time. I think this is an authentication issue.

Comment: Did remove the alternate profile (although I'm positive it was never selected), logged out (turn off sync), closed. Then re-opened, turned sync on. I think I'm now logged in on the sites, seems good so far.

Comment: Nope. One account, Sync off, restart, sync on -> no password fill. Settings -> Autofill -> Passwords -> Google account shows me the data is there, but trying to access the passwords themselves always prompt for a master password (my Google account's).

Answer (score 0):

You're today completely dependent on one browser, Chrome, and on one
device, your computer.

To liberate yourself from this dependency, I would suggest using a
third-party product that is cross-browser and cross-platform.
You could then have your logins on your computer, on your phone,
on Chrome, on Firefox etc. etc.

Here are several possibilities:

- [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/) free and open source
- [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) free and open source
- [Lastpass](https://www.lastpass.com/) commercial, free for one device

Comment: +1 for KeePass, they are available in many platforms and it's free

Comment: I will consider this, but my passwords in Chrome are synchronized on my work computer, home computer, and phone. Not "on one device"

Comment: @Gauthier: All these products are multi-platform and multi-device (except Lastpass requires the commercial version).

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it has to do with Windows-Encryption not working. Guessing Chrome sync tries to download/cache the passwords on the local PC, BUT it needs to do that securely (via encryption) so viruses can't easily access plaintext passwords. Clearly google HAS your passwords since you see it on that *passwords.google.com* site but the Chrome application doesn't.

Some questions:

1. Can you try this google account on another PC? I imagine it'll work & that'll confirm its not the google account
2. If you sign into Chrome with a different google account & enable sync do those passwords show up in Chrome (without accessing *passwords.google.com*) & autofill?
3. In admin command prompt do the following commands, wait for each to finish before progressing to next. Then try to replicate issue:

   - `sfc /scannow` ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e))
   - `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
   - `chkdsk /f` ([link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/))
4. Have you reviewed Event Viewer? Focus on Application & System. Might want to look in Applications and Services, Microsoft, some item here
5. Process of elimination ideas that might help narrow down the issue:

   A. If you don't sign into a google account can you save a password, reboot PC, then it'll auto-fill? If that works it negates my Win encryption not working theory

   B. Try sync/chrome-login with user-chrome-app. When you install Chrome it'll ask for admin credentials, click cancel & it'll install Chrome to appdata instead of Program Files. Logging into PC as limited/non-admin user will also accomplish this. This will confirm if your chrome installation is the problem

   C. As others have pointed out you really should uninstall chrome, reboot PC, then reinstall it. I hope you've tried that already

   D. Try an older version of Chrome

   E. I assume you've tried the various Google articles: [Get your bookmarks, passwords & more on all your devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139); [Fix issues with sync in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9175737?hl=en); [Fix issues with saved payment info & passwords](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7665664?hl=en&ref_topic=7439544)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu. It also happened at home, on an old install of Ubuntu.

Comment: What works is Turn sync off, with Clear local data in the same dialog. Then Turn sync on again after a restart. I need to answer all the questions that are usually stored in cookies again, but it is less painful than doing the round-trip to my Google Account every time.